# Why can GET Request Access OAuth-2.0-Protected File Without Bearer Token?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests

##### Context and Details

I was sent a Hirevue link in response to a job application I submitted and I am messing around with the HTTP requests made by page at that URL. I cannot provide the URL to the page nor the URL that the request I am asking about is sent to without compromising personal information. Thus, I realize this will constrain the help/advice you are able to offer.

Using my browser's Dev Tools, I found that a GET request is sent to [this URL](https://COMPANY.hirevue.com/api/internal/candidates/interviews/INTERVIEW_CODE/?future-practice-questions&include=answers,reuses,sections,poc&_=UNIQUE_VALUE) (which I have redacted for privacy) to retrieve a JSON file (that contains personal data). Among the request headers there is an Authorization header, `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_VALUE`.

From what I understand, this means that the JSON file is protected by the OAuth 2.0 protocol and the Bearer authorization scheme is used to transmit the bearer token to gain access to the JSON file [<sup>1,</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) [<sup>2</sup>](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-2.1). So it seems that one can't access the JSON file without specifying the correct bearer token in the Authorization header field.

##### Problem

When I send the GET request with an empty Authorization header (i.e. `Authorization:` ), however, I am still able to access the JSON file.

**I am using the below python script to send the request:**

```
import requests, json

def get_json(url, auth_token=None):
    # authorization header: scheme is Bearer token
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_token)
    try:
        return response.json()
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print(f"Response to GET request:\n\n{response.content}\n\nExpected Reponse: a JSON string")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # auth token type and token value for API GET request
    my_autho = ('', '')
    
    # redacted URL for my privacy
    url = "https://COMPANY.hirevue.com/interviews/INTERVIEW_CODE"
    data = get_json(url, my_autho)
    print(data)
```

When I omit the Authorization header (i.e. `get_json(url)`) from the GET request I get sent to a 404 page. Thus, I would expect the same thing when I send the empty header.

**That is, I expect the JSONDecodeError exception (which is caught by `get_json`) to be raised:**

```
Response to GET request:

b'\n\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Error 404: Not found  |  HireVue</title>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=8; IE=9" />\n    <link\n      href="https://static.hirevue.com/static/14b0bc1/fonts/Inter-3.15/inter.css"\n  
    rel="stylesheet"\n    />\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.hirevue.com/static/14b0bc1/css/build/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">\n 
   <style type="text/css">\n      body {\n      text-align:center;\n      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;\n      }\n    </style>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h1>Oops!  We couldn\'t find that Page!</h1>\n    <h3>Error 404</h3>\n    <p>Please go back and try again.</p>\n    <img src="https://static.hirevue.com/static/14b0bc1/img-new/hv-logo-color.png" alt="HireVue" border="0">\n  </body>\n</html>\n'

Expected Reponse: a JSON string
```

But as mentioned, my actual output is the JSON string.**So why is it that I can still access the OAuth-2.0-protected JSON file without the token?**

References:

1. HTTP authentication - MDN Web Docs
2. IETF Datatracker - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage